# Ember JS default app stuck on page load

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I've tested this in both v2.2.0-beta.3 and v1.13.13 of the default ember-cli application.

I am using a locked jquery version of 1.11.3 to fix the new "uncaught" error with the newest bower update of jquery.

When I go load the page the default template/application.hbs is rendered correctly with no errors. Ember Inspector sees that it's a loaded ember app with no errors either. However the chrome page is stuck in a loading state.  Whenever I make a change to the application.hbs the app does not trigger livereload to reload the page.

How can I fix this?  I've tried uninstalling node, bower, ember, clearing caches and nothing seems to work. (side note: the default app works on my home computer but not on my work computer).

Comment: Did you `rm -rf bower_components`?

Comment: If your project is on github then can you share the link?